# Drupal PHP installation does not support MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php

I get this rather weird problem while I try to install Drupal 6.22. The web server is nginx+ php5-fpm which I've used with great success before and according to the Ubuntu package manager, php5-mysql is already the newest version (however it does not appear in phpinfo() page). The configuration page is in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini. Here is the error message:

> In your ./sites/default/settings.php
>   file you have configured Drupal to use
>   a mysql server, however your PHP
>   installation currently does not
>   support this database type.

I have created the database and permission.The database declaration line in settings.php seem to be correct.

How can I enable MySQL support and solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" (However it does not appear in phpinfo() page)".

If it is not listed there, then it is not enabled.

Ubuntu usually creates a /etc/php5/conf.d/extension.ini file for each extension package, make sure that exists and contains a line like "extension=mysql.so".

Comment: In fact the extension.ini  did not exist, so I created it in /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d and added 'extension=mysql.so' to it. After restarting php5-fpm, the problem is gone. You're the man Berdir, cheers!

Comment: Note that I meant name_of_the_extension.ini (e.g. mysql.ini), but as long as it works... :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Drupal uses MySQLi to establish the database connection. You could try installing the `php5-mysqli` package if MySQLi is not supported by default.

Comment: Drupal supports both extensions.

Comment: E: Package 'php5-mysqli' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

I always advice new users to install phpmyadmin package. That will install, as a dependency, all the packages you need to properly run drupal.
As you're running with nginx, you'll have to install it later.

Also, you can install drupal from ubuntu's repository

Comment: In my view, both are bad practices, even for newbies. phpmyadmin is the waste of memory and installing drupal from Ubuntu repos is accepting the delay to update packages to reach new releases.

Comment: I agree. It's not recommended at all, but if you're in a hurry and in a testing environment, I don't think it's too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's config.php file should have:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://db_username:db_password@localhost/database_name';
```

OR

```
$db_url = 'mysqli://db_username:db_password@localhost/database_name';
```

MySQL should be already running.

php.ini should have:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

AND/OR

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Comment: I guess you are talking about Windows. I said farewell to that a long time ago :)

Comment: alfish, You can replace "php_mysql(i).dll" with "php_mysql(i).so" in the above and now it's about Linux.